# How to go from Fourier to Chebyshev?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, linear-transformations, chebyshev-polynomials

I need to convert a Fourier cosine series to Chebyshev. I guess the starting point is to Chebyshev expand $\cos(\pi x)$. Is there a closed-form for the Chebyshev coefficients? I expect the answer is yes because the Chebyshev polynomials are like first cousins of the cosines. It's the Chebyshev T polynomials I am referring to.

Any thoughts/ideas anything really welcome.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use $T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos n\theta$ and https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9. I hope Bessel functions qualify for "closed form". :)

Comment: Great, thanks! I guess this is as simple as it gets..